# Mysql realtime messaging

Tags: php, mysql, swift

Not sure if this question is correct for here, if not I shall remove it.

I am creating a social network ios app with backend AWS EC2, I use php and MYSQL to run it.

I am now wondering how would I go about adding instant messaging to my app, realtime kind of like firebase..

Not sure how to go ahead with this or what to use, maybe there is some kind of framework to use with mysql, not sure and that is why I would like to try and get some advice from people with more experience in this area...

Not sure how I would connect all the user details from my current mysql DB to i.e firebase or whatever service I user!

If anyone can help me or put me in the right direction please do!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: MYSQL is not the best route for this.  Look into Google Cloud Messaging or Twilio IP messaging.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup Well I am already using mysql for most of my app, Should I still use those you reccomended?

Comment: Yes.  The amount of queries you would have to handle instant messaging would be far too large.  And these services are ready to go.

Comment: I recommend Firebase. It is used commonly for realtime messaging.

Comment: @sub6resources how would I connect the users form my mysql DB to firebase though?

Comment: if you want instant messaging I suggest mongodb

Comment: @NewbeeDev Would I be able to connect all mysql user's(current users on app) to that?

Comment: @Jack yes you can

Comment: @Jack you better do some research with that to understand how it works

Comment: @NewbeeDev Yep that's what I am doing now!

Comment: Just not sure what would be the best service to use

Comment: This question is too broad.
There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs. This is probably why it has received several downvotes, although the question is not that bad otherwise: the bounty prevents closure, therefore people downvote instead;

Comment: @RandomSeed Thanks for letting me know...But I wasn't really looking for a step to step tutorial of how to do it, but just advice on what would be the best solution and how to go ahead/where to start.. As from the answer below I think I shall use  MYSQL and query every second if it doesn't cost too much and if there's not an easier solution. Please let me know what you think.

Answer (score 14):

It really depends on how much traffic you expect from this. MySQL is completely capable of handling tens of thousands of queries per seconds assuming properly sized hardware, optimal configuration and decent table structure. So even if you poll every second hypothetically you can serve thousands of concurrent users on a single server but here your application server will be the bottleneck not MySQL. You will find that you need to scale that layer before you ever need to worry about the database.

Although MySQL might not be the absolutely best solution available, there are other factors to take into consideration:

- You already have MySQL installed
- You already have knowledge about MySQL
- Your application is already connected to MySQL
- You are already storing some data in MySQL

If you go down the path of introducing a new technology to the stack mind the possible costs:

- You will still need to "connect" your data unless you want to migrate your full dataset to an alternative database which I would warn you about
- You will have to manage it
- You will have to optimize it
- You will have to monitor it
- You will have to learn it

Are you prepared for the additional complexity that managing two database means? (Data sync, additional libraries, scattered expertise, etc.)

> Premature optimization is the mother of all evil.

**Some consideration assuming InnoDB:**

- Keep the row size small (<8k to [avoid off-page blobs](https://www.percona.com/blog/2010/02/09/blob-storage-in-innodb/))
- Have an auto-increment Primary key
- Archive messages (partitioning or dynamically named tables can help here)
- If you have updated columns might want to separate

  - Try to write the message only once and avoid updating if possible

One example:

```
create table message_meta (
    id int unsigned not null primary key auto_increment,
    message_id int unsigned not null,
    recepient_id int unsigned not null,
    is_seen tinyint unsigned not null default '0',
    seen_at timestamp null,
    UNIQUE KEY (recepient_id, message_id),
    KEY (recepient_id)
);

create table message (
    id int unsigned not null primary key auto_increment,
    body varchar(4095),
    created_at timestamp not null default current_timestamp,
    sender_id int unsigned not null,
    KEY (sender_id)
);
```

If you reach a point where MySQL prove to be the bottleneck you can still scale it (replication, sharding, etc). After that you can start using Redis having the most recent messages in there and MySQL as a permanent store.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I would like to say I haven't got an incredible amount of knowledge about MYSQL, I started using AWS EC2 & MYSQL, PHP roughly 3 months ago. If I was to do it all with MYSQL and update every second, what kind of EC2 package would I need..I guess a large one. And If I went the other path, for example "firebase" wouldn't that monitor and sort it self out, after I make all the correct connections? I shall also be doing Push notifications, I think this is possible with mysql or do I need realtime for that too?

Comment: Not sure if you read my comment? if so ignore this..

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't at computer over the weekend. Shortly, yes, MySQL is completely capable of handling that your push notifications. That's more on the app side anyway.

Comment: Ok, well I would definetly prefer to user mysql...But not sure about the poll every second...Any idea roughly what that could cost? I also saw this tutorial with socket.io and node.js https://www.appcoda.com/socket-io-chat-app/ any thoughts? is it possible to user mysql with that?

Comment: I'm sure it is possible. You can connect to MySQL via node.js. It's a matter of implementation how you query the db. With proper indexing and persistent connections the cost on the database is very low (establishing connection and authentication/authorization is a significant overhead especially on millisecond range queries). I've seen MySQL instances with tens of thousands point queries / second running without issues. InnoDB keeps everything in memory and primary key lookups are faster than memcached retrieval: http://yoshinorimatsunobu.blogspot.nl/2010/10/using-mysql-as-nosql-story-for.html

Comment: Ok well I guess I'll try what you suggested first with MYSQL and querying every second. Could you by any chance give me example or show me how I would go about querying like that? to update the messages?

Comment: This should do the trick: http://pastebin.com/juapwmG3 (mind that I updated the answer to include auto_increment which I forgot earlier)

Comment: Ok thanks, But how would that update the message screen everytime a message gets sent? like how would that show the message sent from phone 1 to phone 2 without updating the screen on phone 2

Comment: That's really beyond the point of the database. One example query you would write is: `select * from message_meta meta 
join message msg  on msg.id = meta.messsage_id 
where recepient_id = 2 and message_id > [last seen message_id]
order by created_at` You have to update the screen or at least a part of it. Frequent polling and change only what is relevant. How you handle the communication between the phone and the backend is a whole different discussion. You can use REST with JSON, msgpack, XML or any arbitrary protocol that fits your needs.

Comment: Maybe this tip could help you. I use Signalr framework for chat in asp.net web api (server) and swift, android and windows phone (client). You can change ms sql server to mysql in web api.

Comment: @KárolyNagy I am going to have a proper look at all of this next week. And try and get it working. The bounty was auto delivered to highest votes, which is pretty fair as your answer is probably the best. But I don't know why you only got rewarded +25 rep when bounty was for 50?

Comment: No worries. I assume because the answer wasn't accepted so only half was credited but I don't know for sure how that works. Good luck with the project! Hope it will work out the best.

Answer (score 3):

'Instant' derives from the term 'real-time'; client side code can be used to send requests to the server. Instant messaging applications are complex to write from scratch - there are plenty of things to take into consideration:

- Member registration and login (Session authentication)
- Messaging authentication (Role based access control)
- Protecting against XSS attacks and similar

---

jQuery is a free, open source, framework for JavaScript. You can use a CDN or download it. An example of sending a message would look something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var someSharedUniqueCode = 'Both the recipient and sender uses this key to communicate';
    var message = 'This is an example message';
    $.post('/messages/send/' + message, { communicationKey: someSharedUniqeCode }).done(function(chat) {
    if(chat.State) {
        $('#' + someSharedUniqueCode).append(chat.Message);
    } else {
        $('#' + someSharedUniqueCode).append('Some error message');
    }
});
```

Of course, you would need to set up ReWrite rules inside your `.htaccess` so you can write a controller for the request (MVC), something like this.

```
Router::Map('POST', '/messages/send/[*:m]', function($message) {
    $authKey = $_POST['communicationKey'];
    if(!$authKey && !$message) { return; } // your code on error

    // TODO: Check user is logged in
    // TODO: Check user RBAC is able to communicate in this chat

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $message = new SomeMessageController(); // create a controller and modules that access the database
    echo json_encode(array(
        'State' => $message->setAuthentication($authkey) // example method
                           ->parseMessage($message) // example method
                           ->save() // example method
    ), true);
}, 'Message Sender');
```

---

Remember all of the above information should be stored in the Database and a user should only be able to send messages when they are logged in so you'll need to add a controller to assure they are logged in.

If you're unclear on MVC methodologies, here is an open source [**Router**](http://altorouter.com/) which contains a good set of documentation.

Comment: Plus 1 for the answer. It's not that clear too me though as I haven't an enormous amount of experience with server logic. If you take a look at the other answer and then comments, I have decided I shall do it with my mysql DB but still not sure how to fully deal with it all, if you don't think thats a good solution and yours is better I shall try and understand yours more.

Comment: If you lack experience in the field then you should employee someone, security is **not** worth the risk @Jack

Comment: Well I do plan on doing that once I have most of it finished...So far I have the general likes/following/comments feature set up working with my server. But now I would like to implement the chat part, and then have the server security sorted out.

Comment: Are you using a framework? Or is this project from scratch? I think your best bet is to first and foremost, structure your DB allowing reference to users. Then planning how the messages will be sent and received, for example, a **live** chat will need client-side requests where as an inbox, doesn't entirely need *real-time*. Only alerts and page refresh @Jack

Comment: I have users structured normally I guess, username etc...I am trying to create instagram chat inbox thing, But I'm pretty sure they use realtime and I would prefer the user to recieve to message when it's sent and not have to update the page

Comment: project is from scratch

Comment: I shall probably store the message in a inbox table, and give each chat a uuid which I identify them by

Comment: Wait, you want to be able to send messages to an Instagram account? Or you want something like Instagram has? @Jack

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127739/discussion-between-jack-and-kdot).

Answer (score 3):

I would highly suggest using Firebase as a real time database, and SQL for static content all [running on a Node.js server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start) (which can be run on AWS).

Real time messaging is hard, and without Firebase, it is going to be a long journey.

If you are set on not using Firebase...

1) Use [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) for the real time connection with the client and the server, it is really pretty easy to pass data both ways, while using REST you would need to constantly ping the server for new messages (which is super resource heavy and won't scale as well).

Comment: Ok thanks alot for your response. I saw this tutorial appcoda.com/socket-io-chat-app any thoughts? If I did use firebase wouldn't there be a way to connect my current mysql db with it in a simple way?

Comment: There is a PHP-Firebase client that you can try out. I have not used it, I tend to stay with Node.js and JS.